# Any standalone report viewer with direct connection to SQL database

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, ssrs-2008

Spent all day Google-ing, but could not find any solution.
I need report viewer without server node, but which directly connection to datasource.
Tried to build SSRS report in VS2105, but it requires SSRS service running, and report running user must be granted in Report Manager. That does not give much flexibility.

What I need. I need build report in Report Builder. Then save this report as a file. User runs report file using report viewer, which connects to datasource (SQL). Connection string must be parametric in Viewer (server name, db name, user, pass). So one file could be used in different companies. Viewer must have ability to export in popular formats - Excel, Word, PDF, maybe XML.

What I don't need. Don't need any reporting services or heavy server applications or centralized repositories.

Only one file, which stores connection parameters and report definition.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use the "Data"> "From Other Sources">"SQL Server" option available in Excel. This could then point to a View/Table in SQL that holds results from a stored procedure. You could then apply a pivot table to the extracted data to create your report

Comment: I am using Excel-database combination for my some projects.

Comment: But it's kind a different. Excel is spreadsheet, it's powerfull and highly customizable tool. I need something for end user usage. For example: like you creating form in Adobe forms and send it as PDF file to end user. Or like Crystal Reports viewer. But CR viewer needs Server component to use report dynamically.

Comment: Well @Elshad  (depending on the size of the report!) ...  couldn't you print the final grid-less pivot view of the data to .pdf and distribute that file to the users?

Comment: That would be static file. I need it to be dynamic. So user had ability to recalculate report, which establish connection with database and populates retrieved data. I can't believe there is no reporting solutions without repository storage. Oracle BI, Crystal Reports, SSRS, QlickView - all they work via server component (client-server topology). Another example: if I need send same database structure to multiple clients, I would not install heavy SQL server for each of them. But I could send MS Access file. By the way, as workaround I can use Access's report feature, linking it to SQL db.

Comment: Have you tried PowerBI desktop? It's free and can connect to local files as data sources. It's like building Excel workbooks and sending them to people, they can simply open the PBIX file from Power BI Desktop and use filters/slicers etc to operate your reports or build their own from the data contained in the PBIX file.